# Using 3d-LUT files (*.cube) in CIColorCube - formatting issue?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to wrap a `*.cube` file (which is one of many 3d-LUTs formats) into
`NSData` for use as data input for the `CIColorCube` filter.

The LUTs I'm using are of dimension 32 and although I think we got the length right,
the result is solid gray. My LUTs are 32*32*32 lines of triplets but now I suspect that `CIColorCube` expects a fourth number representing Alpha. is this correct?

All values in my tables are already premultiplied and are of the range `0.0 - 1.0`. My latest attempt was editing my tables and adding 1 as a fourth number in each row. I also deleted any title and text from the original `*.cube` file and saved as `*.txt`. Then I calculated the data length as `32*32*32*4*sizeof(float)` and used 32 as Cube dimension. In this case, I did not receive an error about unexpected length, but the result was all wrong.

Below is the code we are using. The code uses the new `*.txt` file but of course we first started out
with the original `*.cube`. Is this a formatting issue?

Below the code is a snippet from the original `*.cube` file and a snippet from my edited 
`*.txt` attempt.

```
NSString *docsDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *soundFilePath=[[NSString alloc] init];
soundFilePath=[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inkwell-withAlpha.txt"];
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
NSData * cube_data =[NSData dataWithBytes:testData.bytes length:32*32*32*4*sizeof(float)];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorCube"];
[filter setValue:_ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:@2 forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
[filter setValue:cube_data forKey:@"inputCubeData"];

CIImage *outImage = filter.outputImage;
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef outputImageRef = [context createCGImage:outImage fromRect:[outImage extent]];
previewImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputImageRef];
```

**Sample from the start of the original *.cube file:**

```
TITLE "Inkwell"
LUT_3D_SIZE 32
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
0.0039 0.0039 0.0039
0.0235 0.0235 0.0235
0.0353 0.0353 0.0353
0.0549 0.0549 0.0549
0.0745 0.0745 0.0745
0.0863 0.0863 0.0863
...
```

**Sample from start of the *.txt file i'm trying to read:**

```
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1
0.0039 0.0039 0.0039 1
0.0235 0.0235 0.0235 1
0.0353 0.0353 0.0353 1
0.0549 0.0549 0.0549 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
NSData * cube_data =[NSData dataWithBytes:testData.bytes length:32*32*32*4*sizeof(float)];
```

testData.bytes is going to be the character encoding of the values in your document i.e. the character '0' not the number 0. NSData doesn't know that the text file contains numbers and won't do any conversion for you. If you really want to import this from a text document you're going to have to split the string manually with something like:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

then convert each element in the array with

```
- (float)floatValue.
```